# Java JNI Reference Types, passing ByteBuffers around

Tags: java, c, reference, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I create and allocate DirectByteBuffer in native. I then pass this back to Java. Since DirectByteBuffer is allocated in C, it resides in heap memory and is "immune" to Java's garbage collector, right? The only way to free it is from C using free()?

But a call to (*env)->GetObjectRefType() on the buffer object in JNI returns 1, meaning it's a local reference. Local references are said to be automatically freed by Java's GC when JNI method returns. Can someone clarify what is being freed by the GC in this case and should i use the (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, bb) to turn the allocated buffer into Global ref?

C:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_main_Main_byteBufferTest2(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    double *dp = malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    jobject bb = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, (void*)dp, sizeof(double)*100);
    return bb;
}
```

Java:

```
ByteBuffer dbb = byteBufferTest2();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take my answer with a shovel of salt as it's too long ago.

> I create and allocate DirectByteBuffer in native. I then pass this back to Java. Since DirectByteBuffer is allocated in C

That's not exactly true. You allocated `bb` using `(*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer`, so it's JNI.

You allocated `dp` using `malloc`, and that's a different thing. The `bb` is a Java object wrapping `dp`.

> But a call to (*env)->GetObjectRefType() on the buffer object in JNI returns 1, meaning it's a local reference. Local references are said to be automatically freed by Java's GC when JNI method returns.

This makes sense. The byte buffer `bb` gets freed, it's underlying memory `dp` does not.

> should i use the (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, bb) to turn the allocated buffer into Global ref?

I guess so.

Comment: The 'byte buffer `bb`' does not get freed. It doesn't exist. `bb` is a *reference,* not an object. There is a fundamental confusion here and in the question between references and objects.

Comment: @EJP I'm pretty sure, I don't confuse objects and references, but I might have understand something wrong here. Whenever I write "`x` gets free, I obviously mean, "the object pointed by `x` get freed." Concerning `bb`, I assume that the call to `NewDirectByteBuffer` allocates a new byte buffer and returns a reference to it. Currently, I'm unsure how it continues.

Comment: You're confusing freeing of local references by JNI on return with freeing of objects by GC when there are no more references.

Answer (score 0):

Local references are freed when the JNI method returns. However if you return a local reference to Java code, obviosuly the Java code now has a reference. *Objects* can be *garbage-collected* when there are no more *references.* It isn't the same thing.

> Since DirectByteBuffer is allocated in C, it resides in heap memory and is "immune" to Java's garbage collector, right?

Wrong.

> The only way to free it is from C using free()?

Wrong. It is a Java object and is subject to GC like any other Java object. If you try to `free()` it you will get a crash.

> But a call to (*env)->GetObjectRefType() on the buffer object in JNI returns 1, meaning it's a local reference.

Correct.

> Local references are said to be automatically freed by Java's GC when JNI method returns.

No. You're mixing up objects and references. The reference is freed by JNI. The object *can be* freed when there are no more references.

> Should i use the (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, bb) to turn the allocated buffer into Global ref?

Not unless you want to use it again in a subsequent JNI method without having it passed as a parameter.

Comment: Right, Java has a reference and when it loses it, `bb` may be GC'ed. But this is probably not what the OP wants as then there would be no reason for allocating it via JNI, would it?

Comment: @maaartinus I have no idea what the OP wants or why the OP is allocating  it via JNI, and neither do you. I'm just answering the question he asked.

Comment: @EJP If i understood you correctly, the memory location pointed by native *dp (and allocated my malloc) will get freed (GC) if all references to it in Java/JNI are lost, just like any other object? And the only way to keep it is to always have a reference to it in Java or JNI (via global ref)?